# Unity register types using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, ioc-container, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do the following:

```
foreach (var item in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                             .GetTypes()
                             .Where(i => i.GetInterfaces()
                             .Contains(typeof(ITabItem))))
{
    container.RegisterType<ITabItem, item>(nameof(item));
}
```

But I'm getting this error on `item` in the `RegisterType` method:

**Error CS0118  'item' is a variable but is used like a type**

I know that I'm passing an object type but how do I get around this?

**EDIT:** this is the non-dynamic way that works.

```
container.RegisterType<ITabItem, AdminViewModel>(nameof(AdminViewModel));
container.RegisterType<ITabItem, OwnerViewModel>(nameof(OwnerViewModel));
```

Comment: I believe the referred question goes deeper into generics and reflection in general but my question addresses a Unity specific method and the answer for my question specific could not be found in this question. The answer below on the other hand does. So I do not believe my question is a duplicate. Marking this question as duplicate could lead people away from the actual answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the non-generic `RegisterType`, which probably looks something like this:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ITabItem), item, item.FullName);
```